# Ubuntu 12.04.3 -32bit Failed to install grub-efi to /target/

Tags: grub2, uefi, system-installation

I made a live USB using a **12.04.3-32 bit ISO** and trying to install it on **Intel baytrail,EFI based hardware**.During installation i get an error "Failed to install grub-efi to /target/.without the GRUB bootloader,the installed system will not boot".
Here am in a position that i have to use 12.04 LTS,can i know the solution for this issue?

Note: I can able to install 12.04 - 64bit on the same board successfully.

---

I have overcome from this issue by customizing 32 bit ISO file using Ubuntu-builder.
In that am keeping efi part of the Ubuntu-builder file system so during installation my "efi" will be copied to the system /boot folder.

During installation am getting "Failed to install grub-efi to /target/. Without the GRUB bootloader, the installed system will not boot" error then I reboot the system and I can successfully login to installed Ubuntu.

Can I able to suppress this error "Failed to install grub-efi to /target/. Without the GRUB bootloader, the installed system will not boot" while installation?

Answer (score 1):

UEFI is based on executing code in native mode. So no distributions have 32 bit versions for 64 bit systems.

http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/26734.html

You probably can install in BIOS mode if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Oldfred is correct; however, it's also possible to use a 64-bit version of some EFI boot loaders (GRUB 2 and/or ELILO, but I'm not sure if both of them work) to boot a 32-bit kernel. This requires manual configuration, though, so you'll need to understand your EFI boot loader pretty well to attempt it. See [my Web page on EFI boot loaders](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for some background -- but I don't cover the 32-bit kernel on a 64-bit EFI case.

Speaking more broadly, it's seldom necessary or even desirable to install a 32-bit version of Linux on 64-bit hardware. The 64-bit software has long been quite stable. There are performance plusses and minuses for both bit depths, but the biggest minus for 64-bit software applies only if you've got very little RAM by today's standards. If you really need the 32-bit distribution for some reason, installing a 32-bit distribution in VirtualBox may be a better solution than attempting a dual-boot setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome from this issue by customizing 32 bit ISO file using Ubuntu-builder.In that i have installed grub-efi "apt-get install grub-efi" hence Installation goes will without any error.
This is the solution for this issue.

Answer (score -2):

This must be another solution if the other previous ones could solve well. Normally new models use UEFI to boot. That's the problem. **Use legacy boot or old boot method instead of UEFI**.
You can **disable UEFI in BIOS or you can press "F9" or some F keys** to prompt for the boot options, in which case, choose **normal usb boot instead of UEFI**.